# Copy contents of AddedFiles folder to dist folder, after build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, react-native, npm

Using React project on windows with npm to build the project and publish the contents to the 'dist' folder.

All is working as it should.

However I want to add extra files to the dist folder after the project is published.

So far I can get it working with one single file from the root (inside the src folder) so...

```
"copy": "copy \"robots.txt\" \"dist\"",
```

(successfully copies robots.txt to dist)

**I want to copy the entire contents of 'AddesFiles' folder to dist**. But started by trying it with just one file, which says it cant find the file...

```
 "copy": "copy \"\\AddedFiles\\robots.txt\" \"dist\"",
```

also tried

```
"copy": "copy \"\\.src\\AddedFiles\\robots.txt\" \"dist\"",


->SRC
 -robots.txt
    ->AddedFiles
    -robots.txt
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omit the leading backslash to get a relative path:

```
 "copy": "copy \"AddedFiles\\robots.txt\" \"dist\"",
```

If your path [starts with a backslash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats):

> If [...] the directory name begins with the directory separator character, the path is relative from the root of the current drive.

...whereas if it does not:

> Otherwise, the path is relative to the current directory.

---

To copy a folder content, use [`xcopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy) or [`robocopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) instead, e.g.:

```
robocopy AddedFiles dist /E
```

(include subfolders recursively)